# Split a single page desktop app into multiple pages on mobile

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, responsive-design

I am currently developing a single page app using Symfony 2.6 for back end and HTML, CSS and JQuery for the front end. The app is quite modular in the front end with SECTION tags used to divide up content for different purposes. For instance, there is:

- section class="intro"
- section class="twitter-feed"
- section class="tour-info"

etc.

The site uses the SUSY Sass framework (http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/) to create a responsive grid system and as with most responsive sites this causes an average length page on desktop devices to become much longer on mobile devices as the various panels begin to stack.

I therefore wondered whether it was possible to divide a single page desktop app into multiple pages at a certain breakpoint which I could then link to from a mobile-only menu which would be hidden on desktop devices.

Any help much appeciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a separate Twig template for each section. In your one-page layout you could then do something like:

```
<div id="section1">{{ include("path/to/section1.html.twig") }}</div>
<div id="section2">{{ include("path/to/section2.html.twig") }}</div>
```

Next, create a template wrapper for each section for individual rendering, eg.:

*section1-decorated.html.twig*

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}
{% block body %}{{ include("path/to/section1.html.twig") }}{% endblock %}
```

Now create separate actions for these sections for mobile users, where you render these decorated sections:

```
<?php

class FooController
{
    public function section1Action()
    {
        return $this->render('path/to/section1-decorated.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could think in hiding content and showing it, following your single page app aproximation. So you'll only need to hide those sections on mobile and show some links or buttons that will toggle them. It would be lot easier thant chopping into multiple real pages, and the effect would be the same.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi Alvaro, thanks for the reply. Yeah I had thought about that as an approach. However I wondered if there was a way of doing it server-side so that the user doesn't have to download the full page on mobile if they're only interested in one section for example.